# Multiple Index Directives

Tags: nginx

I am looking at the NGINX [wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#multiple-index-directives) (under Multiple Index Directives section) and the example shows a bad practice:

```
http {
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    server {
        server_name www.example.com;
        location / {
            index index.php index.htm index.html;
            # [...]
        }
    }
    server {
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            index index.php index.htm index.html;
            # [...]
        }
        location /foo {
            index index.php;
            # [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Well, I agree that we do not have to repeat the `index` directive in every `location/` block.

Now, as a good practice we have this:

```
http {
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    server {
        server_name www.example.com;
        location / {
            # [...]
        }
    }
    server {
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            # [...]
        }
        location /foo {
            # [...]
        }
    }
}
```

If we see, `location /foo` (in the bad practice code) only use the directive `index.php` but in the another example, `location /foo` inherits the `index` directive.

For example, in the context where we have that the `index.php` could be a process and the `index.html` represents an interface.

How is NGINX going to know that the `location /foo` should return only the `index.php` and not the `index.htm` or `index.html`?

---

If there is a problem with the grammar, please let me know. I also still learning english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right, the Bad and Good examples are not strictly equivalent. In the Bad example, `location /foo` is probably a PHP project, so `index index.php;` is all that's required, but `index index.php index.htm index.html;` will probably work just as well. A single common general statement is better than lots of different specific statements if the former works fine.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your comment. So if `index index.php index.htm index.html;` works for `location /foo`, how does NGINX know which index has to be correct for that location? Sorry, I am still confused on how the resources will be assigned correctly to each location.

Comment: The locations correspond to directories. Nginx looks for the first matching filename in the directory. In the directory `./foo/`, Nginx will first look for a file called `index.php` and only if that file does not exist, will look for a file called `index.htm`, and so on.